# Permalink not working

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have install the site on wordpress and all the setup inside the beta folder and my .htaccess file code are:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteBase /html/beta/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Issue is that when i open the site in new browser, my permlink not working only home page and pages are working, rest link that i have made with the post name that not working, error shown Page not found, but when i refresh the permalink from the admin then all the link working, I set the permalink with post name like: /%postname%/
my site url:  http://ticitech.ch/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress Permalinks not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324647/wordpress-permalinks-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove any .htaccess file and give premalink if possible use bulletproof security for htaccess related issues

Answer (score 0):

I went through same problem and fixing permission issue and checking if .htaccess was right didn't solve it. Then, I after 2 days found out that I need enable rewrite module in apache. You can check this [tutorial](http://www.asishbhattarai.com/wordpress-permalink-fix/) for full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For the Permalink to work, you need to:

1. Give Wordpress permission to edit `.htaccess` file:

   ```
   $ sudo chmod -R 660 /link/to/.htaccess
   ```

   In my case the link was `/var/www/.htaccess`.
   Then save the your preference on permalinks in wordpress settings again to make required changes to `.htaccess` file. Afterwards, for safty's regards, change the permission back to `440`.
2. Enable mod_rewrite and restart Apache ([reference](http://www.asishbhattarai.com/wordpress-permalink-fix/)):

   ```
   $ sudo a2enmod rewrite  
   $ cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled  
   $ grep mod_rewrite *
   $ sudo service apache2 restart
   ```