# permalinks in WordPress not working on localhost but work perfectly on live server

Tags: wordpress

I am getting problem of permalink in WordPress not works at localhost but perfectly work at server.I am also word press developer and get these problem many times.Can you please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: when you save permalinks from wordpress admin, can you see .htaccess file in wp root folder. If it is not created there, you can try copy from server to local and check if it is working in this way.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using ubuntu system then you need to enable apache2 mod_rewrite for your setup. Try this command

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

You will get message like below:

```
Enabling module rewrite.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  service apache2 restart
```

Now enter this command to restart your apache web-server.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This should solve your problem. If the problem persist then you need to change apache config file (`apache2.conf`):

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Search for `<directory>` model for your localhost root directory path. Web-server root path may very based on your apache installed version. It might be `<Directory /var/www/>` or `<Directory /var/www/html/>`. Its mostly like following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`. Save and close the file. Restart your apache web-server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: works at `Kubuntu 20.04`  (`WordPress 6.0.2`)  to `AllowOverride` None to `AllowOverride All`.

Answer (score 1):

if you copy the wordpress instance from a server to your local machine, often you need to reset the permalinks. Just go to the permalinks settings screen and hit save. That usually does the trick for me.

Comment: Glad I scrolled down this far. I thought for sure I'd be in some apache config files.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WAMP on windows go to notification and click on the WAMP icon,
Then go to Apache -> Apache Modules and check `rewrite_module`.

[image: Apache Modules-rewrite_module]

Answer (score 1):

if you use Mac OSX you have

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Search for the following string:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

remove the ‘#’ sign

Now, Search for

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

and replace `AllowOverride None` for `AllowOverride All`

Finally Search for the section `Document Root` and inside this section replace `AllowOverride None` for `AllowOverride All`

Comment: I wasn't able to find `Document Root`, but I did the rest and this solved it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your local server run Apache2? Have you enabled mod_rewrite? Because that is what you need to have permalinks working. Well it's one thing, after that's enabled restart apache2. Then check that your `.htaccess` file is configured properly. Do you have WordPress in a sub-folder, on a sub-domain?

Answer (score 0):

These are the things that I did to fix this.

- change settings > permalink > select 'default' > save
- Fix some php    syntax error (please see apache error logs)
- get the same .htaccess from the root directory of wordpress site you are migrating
- in apache2.conf in Directory > add this > Allowoverride ALL